# The type or namespace name 'List Item' could not be found

Tags: c#

I am making a code to move the elements of a list box up and down. For that, I have made two buttons to move the element up (Move Up button) and down (Move Down button). Here is my code:

```
if (m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex != m_lbOPFfiles.Items.Count && m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListItem item = m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem;
            int index = m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex;
            m_lbOPFfiles.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            lstResdetails.Items.Insert(index + 1, item);
         }
```

Now I am getting the namespace error for ListItem. Can anyone help me rectify it?

Comment: If you had used the "var" keyword instead of ListItem you could have avoided the problem of using the wrong ListItem class altogether...just a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you haven't said what type of application you're writing - Windows Forms? ASP.NET? WPF? Assuming it's ASP.NET, you need:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

at the top of your code. If it's WPF you might want:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
```

EDIT: If it's Windows Forms then there isn't a `ListItem` class. `ListBox.SelectedItem` returns `object`, not `ListItem`. What aspect of a `ListItem` type would you want to use with the `ListBox`? (I'm assuming you're using a `ListBox`.) You can add items to `ListBox.Items` just as objects.

Comment: I want the selected item and store it something so that i can use it later.

Comment: So why do you need ListItem for that rather than just object?

Comment: what syntax do you think would be appropriate for my purpose?

Comment: Just use "object" instead of ListItem. Really, just change the type of your "item" variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. One more help. How to store listbox elements in a string array?

Comment: You'd need to cast each item to a string (or call ToString on it).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're missing the appropriate **using**-directive at the top of your .cs-file, which would be **using System.Web.UI.WebControls;**. You might also be missing the correct assembly (though I doubt it) and should add a reference to the System.Web assembly in your project.

Comment: Quick point of pedantry - that's a using directive, not a using statement. A using statement is the one which calls Dispose automatically.

Comment: is there any alternative for ListItem that can work for me the way i want it to.

Comment: @Jon: Yes you're correct, edited my response.
@sam: Well since I saw you commenting on the other response, take the latter using directive (Jon ;p) from that response and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can just move the cursor onto the identifier and a smart tag will appear. Open it by pressing Ctrl+. or by clicking on it and select whether you want to add the using directive or use a fully qualified name.

On the other hand, if you're using Visual Studio, Intellisense would have told you in its own way that the identifier is currently not available :)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms, if you add objects with ListBox.Items.Add(Object), where Object is an object that you created, the ListBox will be populated by the name of the objects, not by text. Unless you add ListBox.Items.Add(Object.Text), in which case you get the text in the ListBox but you loose the rest of the information in the objects. What we want is a way to emulate what the ListItem class implements in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You are using windows forms, this is why you were not able to access the ListItem Class in the Controls Name space, do the following:
-Add "PresentationFrameWork" (.NET Reference) as a reference to your solution
- add  `using System.Windows.Controls;` to your class file